# Recommend literature for parabolic PDEs.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

My current research is going to deal with mathematical modelling using systems of parabolic PDEs (especially coupled systems of non-homogeneous heat equations). Can anyone recommend good literature for this kind of topic? Thanks.

Comment: Try here: [[http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109042/reference-request-parabolic-pde]]

Then let me know!!